# Sort SQL by two columns and second column as date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am trying to sort my sql result with two columns but its not working for second column which is date.

I know may be there some solution posted before but I am not able to find that.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    order_id,order_name, delivery_date, created_at 
FROM 
    orders 
WHERE 
    store_client_id = '1192' 
    AND delivery_date != '' 
ORDER BY 
    order_id DESC, 
    CAST('delivery_date' AS DATE) DESC 
LIMIT 0,15
```

And result I am getting:

[image]

Order id is being sorted properly and date is not working.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated in advance.

Comment: First of all you need to get rid of quotes wrapping `delivery_date` in `CAST('delivery_date' AS DATE)`, and why do you need casting to date, isn't already that column is of date type ?

Comment: This is how Order by 2 columns work

It will first sort by first coloumn, then if 2 or more rows have same data for 1st coloumn only then those rows which are having same data for first coloum will be sorted based on 2nd coloum. So I dont see a problem in the output and it seems to be working as expected. Let me know if I missed anything from the question

Comment: @ Barbaros Özhan Okay, If I try without cast then too it is not working.

Comment: @Sameer It is not sorting the dates. That is the problem.

Comment: remove quotes from delivery_date.your query first sort rows based on order_id.If more then one rows have same order_id then it sort based on date.I don't see any problem here. if you want to sort based on dates then swap order of delivery_date and order_id.

Comment: @PKP I have tried both but the result is none. same as attached screenshot. When I switch first delivery_date first and then order id it works but not in reverse order.

Comment: is there any rows which have same order_id?

Comment: @PKP No, You can see also in my screenshot attached.